# How to group data in SQL table to show every combination?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008, and this completely imaginary scenario and data, how can I transpose this (incomplete) database table?

[image: (incomo]

The final table should contain every Town in its City and every combination of thee (different) animals associated with that town and city.

[image]

I have been considering a pivot but can't find a solution that will solve this particular problem.

I am looking to understand the concept, so I can apply the technique to my real data, which is a bit more complex.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the meaning of PIVOT. PIVOT is for transposing rows to columns...

Comment: Yes I was getting confused. Any suggestions about how the above could be implemented?

Comment: You may check my solution. You needed CROSS JOINs.

Comment: Dan, do you recall whether the below answer assisted you with your use case? Although it is not mandatory on Stack Overflow, we encourage question authors to accept good answers if they are able to.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you need is CROSS JOIN the table with itself three times and then filtering out doubles and triples.

You may check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fadca/7)

The code is :

```
SELECT  T1.Country,
        T1.Town,
        T1.Pet AS Pet1,
        T2.Pet AS Pet2,
        T3.Pet AS Pet3
FROM    Pets T1
        CROSS JOIN Pets T2
        CROSS JOIN Pets T3
WHERE   T1.Pet <> T2.Pet
        AND T2.Pet <> T3.Pet 
        AND T1.Pet <> T3.Pet    
        AND T1.Country = T2.Country
        AND T1.Country = T3.Country
        AND T1.Town = T2.Town
        AND T1.Town = T3.Town
```

Comment: These are not cross joins. They are inner joins (non-equi joins to be precise). You merely moved the join criteria to the `WHERE` clause, which is considered bad style.

Comment: As to the result: You are returning too many rows, because you have all combinations multifold. Change `<>` to `<` in order to avoid this.